# Highlight the output of successful c++ build on a different color VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode to do some small compiling and building. It would be great if I can visually see that the build has succeeded in a different color. As you can see in the image attached, it would be nice to see the `Build finished successfully` in bold green. While this is not the most pressing thing, I would like to know if it is possible.

[image]